# How to scrape the number of followers of questions from Quora using Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby, debugging, web-scraping, quora

I have been trying to implement a project to scrape questions from Quora based on a topic and have been using this resource as a foundation - https://github.com/Theminijohn/quora-scraper
As shown in this page, the followers are being extracted as expected for each question. However upon implementing the same in my system, for each question the follower count is shown zero even if it is not zero. 
[Column Follower always has zero value as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhtfZ.png)

The code which is responsible for extracting the number of followers is this:

```
follower_count = q.css('.FollowActionItem .icon_action_bar-label span > span:last-child').text.to_i
```

Everything else is working as expected. What am I missing here?

Edit: The whole Code snippet is as follows:

```
    require 'rubygems'
require 'ruby-progressbar'
require 'Nokogiri'
require 'csv'
require 'pry'

ENGAGEMENT_THRESHOLD = 5

# init progressbar
progressbar = ProgressBar.create( format:         '%a %bᗧ%i %p%% %t',
                                  progress_mark:  ' ',
                                  remainder_mark: '･')

# parse file
doc = File.open("input.html") { |x| Nokogiri::HTML(x) }
questions = doc.css('.TopicAllQuestionsList .pagedlist_item')

# identifiers
canonical_link = doc.at('link[rel="canonical"]')['href']
topic_name = canonical_link.match(/quora.com\/topic\/(.*)/)[1]

# update progressbar
progressbar.total = questions.count

# prepare csv
unless File.exist?('quora-data.csv')
  CSV.open("quora-data.csv", "w+") do |csv|
    csv << [
      "Topic", "Title", "Followers", "Answers", "Ratio", "Engagement potential",
      "Last action", "Parsed time", "Question link"
    ]
  end
end

questions.each do |q|
  link = "https://www.quora.com" + q.css('a.question_link').attr('href').value
  title = q.css('a.question_link').text.strip
  answer_count = q.css('.QuestionFooter .answer_count_prominent').text.strip.to_i
  follower_count = q.css('.FollowActionItem .icon_action_bar-label span > span:last-child').text.to_i
  ratio = "#{follower_count}/#{answer_count}"

  if answer_count == 0
    take_action = (follower_count >= ENGAGEMENT_THRESHOLD) ? "Yes" : "No"
  else
    take_action = ((follower_count / answer_count) >= ENGAGEMENT_THRESHOLD) ? "Yes" : "No"
  end

  # timestamps
  raw_time = q.css('.QuestionFooter .question_timestamp').text.strip
  last_action = raw_time.include?("Last requested") ? "Requested" : "Followed"

  if raw_time.include?('ago')
    if raw_time.scan(/(\d*)h/).flatten.any?
      hours_ago = raw_time.scan(/(\d*)h/).flatten[0].to_f
      parsed_time = (DateTime.now - (hours_ago / 24)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    elsif raw_time.scan(/(\d*)m/).flatten.any?
      minutes_ago = raw_time.scan(/(\d*)m/).flatten[0].to_f
      parsed_time = (DateTime.now - (1.0 / 24 / 60)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    end
  else
    if raw_time.count("0-9") > 0
      parsed_time = Date.parse(raw_time).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    else
      parsed_time =
        (Date.today < Date.parse(raw_time)) ? (Date.parse(raw_time) - 7) : Date.parse(raw_time)
    end
  end

  CSV.open("quora-data.csv", "a+") do |csv|
    csv << [
      topic_name, title, follower_count, answer_count, ratio,
      take_action, last_action, parsed_time, link
    ]
  end

  # move progressbar
  progressbar.increment
end
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0099)file:///C:/Users/DIGANTA/quora/quora-scraper/All%20Questions%20on%20Data%20Science%20-%20Quora.html -->
<html lang="en" class="js-wf-loaded"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><link rel="icon" href="https://qsf.fs.quoracdn.net/-3-images.favicon.ico-26-ae77b637b1e7ed2c.ico"><link rel="preload" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://qsf.fs.quoracdn.net/-3-fonts.q-icons.q-icons.woff2-26-9afc20a49e3ef2cf.woff2"><link rel="preload" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://qsf.fs.quoracdn.net/-3-fonts.q_serif.q_serif_regular.woff2-26-7ace3bc4cbe404d9.woff2"><link rel="preload" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://qsf.fs.quoracdn.net/-3-fonts.q_serif.q_serif_regular_italic.woff2-26-9d81ab3229809d01.woff2"><link rel="preload" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://qsf.fs.quoracdn.net/-3-fonts.q_serif.q_serif_semibold.woff2-26-b55bf39d9018ace9.woff2"><link rel="preload" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://qsf.fs.quoracdn.net/-3-fonts.q_serif.q_serif_semibold_italic.woff2-26-4c39f22524232bf2.woff2"><script src="./input_files/sdk.js.download" async="" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="file:///C:/Users/DIGANTA/quora/quora-scraper/All%20Questions%20on%20Data%20Science%20-%20Quora_files/sdk.js.download" async="" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script async="" src="file:///C:/Users/DIGANTA/quora/quora-scraper/All%20Questions%20on%20Data%20Science%20-%20Quora_files/analytics.js.download"></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="file:///C:/Users/DIGANTA/quora/quora-scraper/All%20Questions%20on%20Data%20Science%20-%20Quora_files/widgets.js.download"></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="file:///C:/Users/DIGANTA/quora/quora-scraper/All%20Questions%20on%20Data%20Science%20-%20Quora_files/sdk.js(1).download"></script><script type="text/javascript">window.Q = {"fontFamilies": ["q-icons", "q_serif"], "errorSamplingRate": 1.0, "revision": "41e9b4435b78728ddf351e72a6dc45ca9708ebc2", "subdomainSuffix": "quora.com"};window["webpackManifest"] = {"ads_manager": "https://qsc.fs.quoracdn.net/-3-chunk.web.ads_manager.js.out-34-1e09a2ca57288a3c.webpack", "content_widgets": "https://qsc.fs.quoracdn.net/-3-chunk.web.content_widgets.js.out-34-9a6c124eee999cb7.webpack", "dev": "https://qsc.fs.quoracdn.net/-3-chunk.web.dev.js.out-34-5d22ece0a38f03a1.webpack", "internal": "https://qsc.fs.quoracdn.net/-3-chunk.web.internal.js.out-34-2e41b1b9af1f0f88.webpack", "qtext2": "https://qsc.fs.quoracdn.net/-3-chunk.web.qtext2.js.out-34-b3d77df0693a06da.webpack", "main": "https://qsc.fs.quoracdn.net/-3-chunk.web.main.js.out-34-835b38fb05330b9f.webpack", "firebase": "https://qsc.fs.quoracdn.net/-3-chunk.web.firebase.js.out-34-eadc5f3144befc37.webpack", "publisher_dashboard": "https://qsc.fs.quoracdn.net/-3-chunk.web.publisher_dashboard.js.out-34-0c43bcc87e209b23.webpack"};window["webpackChunks"] = ["main"];window["PAGE_IS_MOBILE"] = false;var assetErrs=[];document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(e){if(0!==assetErrs.length){var s="assets="+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(assetErrs)),t=new XMLHttpRequest;t.open("POST","/ajax/log_browser_asset_load_error_3RD_PARTY_POST",!0),t.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"),t.setRequestHeader("Accept","*/*"),t.send(s.replace(/%20/g,"+"))}}),window.addAssetErr=function(e){e&&assetErrs.push(e)};
```

Complete HTML file can be found here- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_X86tq5TTw4ikk-hQ2Ixd13Y_hR4scBg/view?usp=sharing

The HTML containing info of the number of followers is:

```html
<div class="FollowActionItem ItemComponent primary_item u-relative"><span id="wVP1Ux4a11"><a class="ui_button ui_button--styled ui_button--FlatStyle ui_button--FlatStyle--gray ui_button--size_regular u-inline-block ui_button--non_link ui_button--supports_icon ui_button--has_icon" href="#" role="button" action_click="QuestionFollow" action_target="{&quot;qid&quot;: 44394942, &quot;type&quot;: &quot;question&quot;}" id="__w2_wVP1Ux4a27_button"><div class="ui_button_inner" id="__w2_wVP1Ux4a27_inner"><div class="ui_button_icon_wrapper u-relative u-flex-inline"><div id="__w2_wVP1Ux4a27_icon"><span class="ui_button_icon" aria-hidden="true"><svg width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g stroke="none" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linecap="round">
        <g id="follow" class="icon_svg-stroke" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1.5">
            <path d="M14.5,19 C14.5,13.3369229 11.1630771,10 5.5,10 M19.5,19 C19.5,10.1907689 14.3092311,5 5.5,5" id="lines"></path>
            <circle id="circle" cx="7.5" cy="17" r="2" class="icon_svg-fill" fill="none"></circle>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg></span></div></div><div class="ui_button_label_count_wrapper"><span class="ui_button_label" id="__w2_wVP1Ux4a27_label">Follow</span><span class="ui_button_count" aria-hidden="true" id="__w2_wVP1Ux4a27_count_wrapper"><span class="bullet"> · </span><span class="ui_button_count_inner" id="__w2_wVP1Ux4a27_count">1</span></span></div></div></a></span></div>
```

Comment: Could you kindly share the full setup of the gem, so that other could run the code more easily?

Comment: Can you also provide the snippet of HTML you're trying to scrape? Whatever you're grabbing is an empty string, so when you `to_i` it it's 0

Comment: What happens if you try to select these elements from developer console? Quora uses jQuery, so you can try with jQuery('.FollowActionItem .icon_action_bar-label span > span:last-child'). To do this, you should be on the page, where number of followers can be seen.

Comment: @MatildaSmeds I have updated the question with the complete code snippet. You can try the code by using any saved html of a quora page of a particular topic.

Comment: @JayDorsey added the HTML snippet. If you require the complete HTML file please let me know. Thanks

Comment: I don't have Quora account, sorry. Did you check that the selector returns values from developer console, like I suggested? The HTML snippet you have included doesn't contain actual data. If you are parsing against this snippet, the selector will not return anything.

Comment: @MatildaSmeds The whole HTML file is quite big. You dont need quora to run the code you can just use the HTML file. If you need the same, let me know. Dvevloper Console will be only useful if I'm having one single quora question per page which is not how it is working, the code parses through all scrolled questions of a topic in Quora. Please visit the GitHub page which I've added which explains the working.

Comment: In the sample you provided, I don't see _any_ selectors named `icon_action_bar-label`, so I wouldn't expect that to work at all. It looks like the data is wrapped inside a `ui_button_count_inner` selector, so you might try grabbing that with something like `q.css('.FollowActionItem .ui_button_count_inner).text.to_i`

Comment: @JayDorsey worked with a slight discrepancy which I was able to solve. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, just saw this. Were you able to solve your issues?

Comment: @MiniJohn yes I was. Thank You!